# Not able to login to a website using python POST request

Tags: post, python-requests

I am trying to login to https://www.oreilly.com/member/login  using a POST request from python, but am unable to.

I am using following code snippet.

```
import requests;  session = requests.session(); response = session.post('https://www.oreilly.com/member/login',data={"email":'my_email_id',"pas
...: sword":'my_password'})
```

This gives following response.

```
response <Response [404]>;
```

`response.text '<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang="en">\n<head>\n<meta charset="utf-8">\n<title>Error</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n<pre>Cannot POST /member/login</pre>\n</body>\n</html>\n'`

Please help. Thank you so much !!

Answer (score 1):

You used `data` instead of `json`, also, the login url that you used was wrong. Here is my code:

```
import requests

login_url = "https://www.oreilly.com/member/auth/login/"

payload = {
    "email": "your_email",
    "password": "your_password"
}

headers_ = {
"Content-Type": "application/json"
}

r = requests.post(login_url, json=payload, headers=headers_)

print(r.text)
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! This works perfectly !! One question. How did you figure out the correct url ? It would be really helpful to know that.

Comment: You can use the Developer Tool from Chrome, you can open it with "F12". Then go to the Network Tab and let it run in the background while logging in, search for login or something similar to that, then look what kind of request it is (GET, POST...) and use that URL. Let me know if you need it in more detail!